# linux - Is Debian "lighter" than Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian

I currently run Linux Mint 14 KDE on a "semi-old" machine I use for working and surfing the web - it was the first Linux system I ever used (running away from old Win XP), so I picked a complete system that would have most of my basic needs installed (I didn't even know what exactly all those needs were at the time).

The thing is, my computer is becoming really old and Mint is a cluttered system, and for the next installation I'm going to try and install a "raw" system and get everything from the online repos.

My question is: **Since Ubuntu is Debian-based, does that make it consume more resources than its base system? If that isn't the difference, which one is "lighter" in that sense?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Debian is the 'mother' if you like of both Ubuntu and Mint and is focused more on stability and security than cutting edge features.  That said, it is very extensible so you can add bells and whistles if needed.

In terms of system resources, from experience Debian is lighter weight than Ubuntu, but that's subjective and I'm sure could be argued against <- ambiguous enough?!?

There's an interesting article here on Ubuntu vs. Debian;

http://www.datamation.com/open-source/ubuntu-vs.-debian.html

The main thing really is what do you want to use it for?  Are you hell bent on a Debian variant or would you consider moving to another distro - ArchLinux (https://www.archlinux.org/) for example is very frugal in terms of resources, it even runs well on a 256Mb raspberry pi, but then again raspbian (Debian based) does too.

For super lightweight linux there's always **D** amn **S** mall **L** inux too; http://www.damnsmalllinux.org/

Comment: Must add that DSL is Debian based, but has some quirky differences

Comment: To put it more simple, they share the same skeleton, but each have its default software pre-installed. Debian having the less by default.

Comment: @Kwaio nicely put, I think I was being a little wordy this afternoon :)

Comment: I have a gift for being unable to be "wordy" ;) Always good to have a "TL;DR" section.

Comment: Is DSL fully compatible with Debian software?

Comment: Not fully, but I've had some success.  Give it a try?